# Material UI Select component under the hood

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently working on implementing my own react UI library,
and I faced a challenge while trying to implement the select component,

for the select options, I want them to be passed as children components with "key" and "value" attributes but I'm stuck figuring out how the parent component should handle a click event on the options and how to change the styling of selected options.
There is another issue, I want to have a highly customizable dropdown so not only the options can be provided but other components like headers and so, and I don't want those to be considered as options by the parent component

here is an example with material UI where they use **MenuItem** for options and a **ListSubHeader** as well as select children.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujs7S.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvMgp.png)

Comment: Can you post your code instead of the images?

Comment: I didn't start the code yet, I'm currently trying to figure out how I can possibly do it